# Progress bar on file upload on Phonegap with Framework7

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, html-framework-7, phonegap

I am trying to upload an image to a server using phonegap/cordova and Framework7. I am able to upload the image without any issues, but how can I display a progress bar with the upload status?

**My HTML:**

```
<img onclick="getImage()" src="img/camera.png" width="50%"/>
<div class="progressbar" id="progressbar">
```

**Javascript/JQuery**

```
function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
 var options = new FileUploadOptions();
 options.fileKey = "file";
 options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
 options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
 console.log(options.fileName);
 var params = new Object();
 params.value1 = "test";
 params.value2 = "param";
 options.params = params;
 options.chunkedMode = false;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, "http://www.my-server.com/upload.php", function(result){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
 }, function(error){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
 }, options);

 // I have tried this to show progress but it doesn't work.
     $("#progressbar").show();
    ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

    perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

    $("#progressbar").progressbar({value:perc});

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the framework7 docs :

```
var progressbar = $$('#progressbar');
myApp.setProgressbar(progressbar, prec);
```

For other options refer on [Progressbar framework7](https://framework7.io/docs/progressbar.html)